# "Stockmarkets" vs. "stock markets"

Tags: word-choice, orthography, hyphenation, compounds, spacing

I am having trouble with the difference between *stockmarkets* and *stock markets* — or should it be *stock-markets*? In some articles it is introduced as *stockmarkets*, but that term is not found in the dictionary.

I need more clarification about the difference between them and which one is more correct to use.

Comment: "stockmarket" = "stock-market" -- see a good dictionary. I would suggest using the word "stockmarket," which is already well-established.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is *[Stock Market](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stock_market)* or equity market: (from Wikipedia)

> - is the aggregation of buyers and sellers (a loose network of economic transactions, not a physical facility or discrete entity) of stocks (also called shares); these may include securities listed on a stock exchange as well as those only traded privately.

Definition of  '*[Stock market](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/stockmarket.asp)*': (from Investopedia)

> - The market in which shares of publicly held companies are issued and traded either through exchanges or over-the-counter markets. Also known as the equity market.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stock%20market%2Cstock-market&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstock%20market%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstock%20-%20market%3B%2Cc0) stock market vs stock-market

Personally I have very rarely seen it as one word. Ngram has no evidence of stock market as a single word.

Comment: And the NGram results are picking up the use of the hyphenated *stock-market* as an adjective (hyphenating compound nouns when used as adjectives is commonly recommended). [See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stock-market_ADJ%2C+stock-market_NOUN&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstock%20-%20market_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstock%20-%20market_NOUN%3B%2Cc0). I would use *stock market* for the noun.